# Using result raster of Semi-automatic classification to obtain spatial statistics?

Tags: qgis, raster, remote-sensing, classification

I finished classification (use SACP in QGIS), and got a classificated raster.
Now I want to obtain characteristics such as sum area of class, areas of different  polygons separately, etc.

I tried use shp. file, which created in SACP (i tried calculate areas by export/add the geometry field); I tried to use r.stats GRASS command but i have not gotten  characteristics of area linked with Class.

Maybe somebody can give good suggestion or ready recipe about this?